# How to retrieve data from Object [Firebase unique key]

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[This is the data that i want to retrieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRHNX.png)

[How can I retrieve the data without knowing the unique ID?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkkIh.png)

```
        var query = firebase.database().ref("/Venue").orderByKey();
    query.on("value", function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
                var key = childSnapshot.key;
                var childData = childSnapshot.val();
                console.log(childData);                                                                                         
            });
        });
```

Comment: since ....Data has exactly one property ... `Object.values(childData.Data)[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Object.values` to help. it returns an array of values of properties of an object

Since `.Data` has exactly one property, you can easily get its value, it will be at index 0

```
var query = firebase.database().ref("/Venue").orderByKey();
query.on("value", function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        var key = childSnapshot.key;
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        console.log(Object.values(childData.Data)[0]); // change
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.values`:

```js
var obj = {
  Venue: {
    Block_A: {
      Data: {
        Date: "19/03/2019",
        Humi: 30,
        Temp: 50,
        Time: "12:56"
      }
    }
  }
};
console.log(Object.values(obj.Venue.Block_A.Data));
```

Comment: but ... where's the "random unknown key" :p